# "Fix" Angular UTC Dates

Tags: json, angular, date

I am building an Angular 2.x app that consumes a REST API for its data.  The API delivers some date information in JSON form:

```
  "punchDate": "2017-05-17T00:00:00",
  "timezone": "CST"
```

If I ask Angular to print punchDate to screen (in my timezone which is CST) it will show: May 16, 2017, 7:00:00 PM.

When that date gets assigned to a date picker it says the same, "May 16, 2017" when what the API really intended for me to do was have the date picker say "May 17, 2017".

The JSON response comes out of the API, into an Angular Service which converts it to a TypeScript interface, and that service get used throughout the app.

**Class:**

```
export interface Punch{ 
    punchDate: Date;
    timezone: string;
}
```

**Service Method:**

```
public get = (id: number): Observable<Punch> => {
    return this.http.get('/api/punch/' + id).map(res => res.json());
}
```

How do I get Angular to treat this date how the API intended?

Plunkr to demonstrate problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hYYRbyWLFBvzh4uGBJay

Answer (score 0):

This might be something particular to your browser. they both say 17th when I run your code.

[image]

Comment: Are you in the UTC timezone (or is your computer set to UTC)?

Comment: I can be, let me try that.

Comment: I changed my time zone on the PC, re-started the browser, tried different browser, I still see the same thing.

Comment: You are right that something funky is going on.  Chrome reports the date as the 16th, IE as the 17th.

Comment: If I remove the date pipe then the two are the same across browsers (which I would have expected as well).  So maybe the datepipe is what was making my demo plunkr show that problem (only in Chrome though apparently).  I'm still convinced it's an interpretation of "local time" causing the issue, but maybe it's inside the date picker we are using or something - need to investigate more.  Thank you for the help.